# Redirect non www to www using ALB Ingress Controller

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to redirect a `non www` request to `www`. I checked the annotations here https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/ingress/annotation/ but could not find specific to non www to www redirect.

I already have a `http` to `https` redirect set and it's working.

below is my ingress resource manifest file.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: eks-learning-ingress
  namespace: production
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: ard878ef678df
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
  labels:
    app: eks-learning-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.myhost.in
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /*
          backend:
            serviceName: ssl-redirect
            servicePort: use-annotation
        - path: /*
          backend:
            serviceName: eks-learning-service
            servicePort: 80
```

Any help in this would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the [alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/ingress/annotation/#actions)? As it "Provides a method for configuring custom actions on a listener, such as for Redirect Actions."

Comment: hi @OhHiMark, thanks for your reply. In my case since my domain is hosted on godaddy and i am unable to add a root / bare domain record pointing to DNS name of my ALB, i am not able to use actions.

Answer (score 12):

There are 2 ways of doing non-www to www redirections, 1. using `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions`, 2. `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions`.

---

### [alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.7/guide/ingress/annotations/#actions)

> alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.${action-name} Provides a method for
> configuring custom actions on a listener, such as for Redirect
> Actions.
>
> The action-name in the annotation must match the serviceName in the
> ingress rules, and servicePort must be use-annotation.

We need to have one more annotation, which tells ALB how to configure redirection:

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.redirect-to-www: >
    {"Type":"redirect","RedirectConfig":{"Host":"www.myhost.in","Port":"443","Protocol":"HTTPS","StatusCode":"HTTP_302"}}
```

And one more host rule to catch your request domain `myhost.in` and redirect to `www.myhost.in`

```
- host: myhost.in
  http:
    paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: redirect-to-www
          servicePort: use-annotation
```

### [alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.7/guide/ingress/annotations/#conditions)

> alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.${conditions-name} Provides a
> method for specifying routing conditions in addition to original
> host/path condition on Ingress spec.
>
> The conditions-name in the annotation must match the serviceName in
> the ingress rules. It can be a either real serviceName or an
> annotation based action name when servicePort is "use-annotation".

In addition to the annotation we have added above, we continue to add conditions to annotations to filter the request but no need to have the host rule above.

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.redirect-to-www: >
    {"Type":"redirect","RedirectConfig":{"Host":"www.myhost.in","Port":"443","Protocol":"HTTPS","StatusCode":"HTTP_302"}}
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.redirect-to-www: >
    [{"Field":"host-header","HostHeaderConfig":{"Values":["myhost.in"]}}]
```

We modify the existing host rule you currently have to achieve the redirection.

```
- host: www.myhost.in
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /*
          backend:
            serviceName: redirect-to-www
            servicePort: use-annotation
        - path: /*
          backend:
            serviceName: ssl-redirect
            servicePort: use-annotation
        - path: /*
          backend:
            serviceName: eks-learning-service
            servicePort: 80
```

### Update for `networking.k8s.io/v1`

```
- host: www.myhost.in
  http:
    paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: redirect-to-www
            port:
              name: use-annotation
```

Comment: "In addition to the annotation we have added above, we continue to add conditions to annotations to filter the request but no need to have the host rule above."

This does not work. The controller _would_ create a condition that matches **both** `www.myhost.in` and `myhost.in` which ends up in a redirect loop. Because of that this rule will never be created.

The only option in this case is to create another host rule, as described in the first option.

Comment: From the ALB controller [docs](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.6/guide/ingress/annotations/#conditions):
"alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.${conditions-name} Provides a method for specifying routing conditions **in addition to original host/path condition on Ingress spec.**" (emphasis is from the original article).