# NGINX Ingress Redirection Based On Domain Name

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, load-balancing, nginx-ingress

I have two domain names, each for different applications hosted in a single kubernetes cluster.

Is there a way to configure ingress to redirect to the different apps based on the hostname in the request it receives?

For example:

`www.app1.com` and `www.app2.com` point to the same IP address. However, I want `www.app1.com` to redirect to `/appABC` while [www.app2.com](http://www.app2.com) redirect to `/appXYZ`.

I have attempted to capture the host name and use this to determine the redirect but it doesn't work.

Is what I'm trying to do possible with NGINX?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,it is Possible. You must need to create two configuration files and point them to their respective paths. Please follow this [link](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/how-to-configure-multiple-domains-with-nginx-on-ubuntu/) for more info and refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62902814/kubernetes-ingress-nginx-redirecting-domain-and-also-apply-to-all-redirected-dom) also to get further idea on how to use.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, using the [NGINX Playground](https://nginx-playground.wizardzines.com/), I was able to come up with this solution.

```
...
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
    set $is_app1_base 1;
    set $is_app2_base 1;
    if ($host !~ "^.*app1\.com$" ) {
        set $is_app1_base 0;
    }
    if ($request_uri != "/") {
        set $is_app1_base 0;
        set $is_app2_base 0;
    }
    if ($is_app1_base = 1) {
      return 301 $scheme://$host/appABC;
    }
    if ($host !~ "^.*app2\.com$" ) {
      set $is_app2_base 0;
    }
    if ($is_app2_base = 1) {
      return 301 $scheme://$host/appXYZ;
    }
```

In case you're wondering why a number of `if statement`s had to be used this way, [NGINX is not that great with if statements and logical operations](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

Another caveat worth stating here is that all ingresses associated with this NGINX controller will be affected by this `server-snippet`; Because `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet` is a global annotation.